# Preferences.flush writes to registry in alphabetical order

Tags: java, preferences

So, I am developing a program that reads and writes from/to Windows registry. The problem is, when I save my data to the registry, it saves in alphabetical order. Is there any way to make the Preferences not save it in alphabetical order?

Comment: Probably not.  The implementation of Preferences is internal;  it doesn’t even have to use the registry (and obviously doesn’t on systems other than Windows).  Why is it a problem?

Comment: It is a problem because I have an array full of Color Objects and they are not ordered in alphabetical order, so when I use the preferences to fetch the colors and apply them to my array, the wrong colors are assigned to the wrong indices. I thought of a solution though, if it works I will post it.